# Class Structure For Parsing Tree of Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I'm trying to create object + filter classes in order to parse an object tree. Trying to figure out the best way to structure the code, hoping someone can provide some insight. I'm trying to abstract out so that I can filter different object types but the base structure is (this isn't exact code just similar example I quickly wrote)

```
class ObjectOne:
     def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3, field4):
         self.field1 = field1
         self.field2 = field2
         self.field3 = field3
         self.field4 = field4
         self.parent = None
         self.children = []

class FilterOne:
     def __init__(self, field1=None, field2=None, field3=None, field4=None):
         self.field1 = field1
         self.field2 = field2
         self.field3 = field3
         self.field4 = field4

     def is_match(self, obj):
         for f in ["field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"]:
             filter_val = getattr(self, f, None)
             if not filter_val:
                 continue
             item_val = getattr(obj, f)
             if filter_val != item_val:
                 return False
          return True

obj = ObjectOne(True, True, True, True)
fil = FilterOne(field1=True, field4=False)
fil.is_match(obj) # False
```

This works fine and all but I don't like having to write the same fields over again. I tried dynamically creating a dataclass and extending from that which again also worked but I haven't been able to figure out the abstraction I'm looking for.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can maybe write this differently? Not necessarily looking for a magic solution just a cleaner idea that doesn't duplicate the same fields so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as simple as:

```
def is_match(filter_, obj):
    return all(getattr(obj, n) == v for n, v in filter_.__dict__.items() if v is not None)
```

It works if you use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (which is very idiomatic and encouraged) or if you just don't over-engineer you classes with properties, `__getattr__` etc.

Just in case, an example of dataclass usage:

```
@dataclass
class SomeClass:
    f1: int
    f2: str

@dataclass
class Filter:
    f1: Optional[int] = None
    f3: Optional[bool] = None
```